# Excel : All other language symbols are getting converted to?

Tags: excel, encoding

I'm dealing with 2 kinds of problems in excel:
1st - I need to copy some filenames but those with other language text get converted to ???

```
Example: file name ="foosｄアプ bar" will look like "foos??? bar in excel"
```

2nd - Also, symbols like bullet point in format â€¢ (utf-8) needs to be converted to their equivalent in excel.

```
Example : Text in excel = "â€¢ Be polite" needs to be converted to "• Be polite"
```

How do I solve this (Treat me as a beginner)

Comment: What is the source of your text? What encoding does it use?

Comment: text like â€¢ are in utf-8 encoding as they are getting scraped in utf-8 encoding. It must be noted that while reflecting on a website front end, they get automatically converted to their equivalent.

Comment: I'm not sure about the encoding used for filenames as they are getting downloaded from other websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st one, you can use pasting the filenames as unicode text and for the second follow a trick to open the csv as a notepad and then save it as utf-8 csv.